# Syntactic use of " false" . After " false" can I write anything I want? ( Not a semantic question on " ex falso sequitur quodlibet")

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

If the proof below  proof is correct, I'd like to know what is the name of the rule involving " false" that is used here.

This question is not on " ex falso sequitur quodlibet". From false follows anything, that is clear from a semantic point of view. My question deals with  the syntactic use of the propositional constant " false" and  the official rules governing this use.

[image]

Comment: A "proof" that doesn't tell you what rules its using to perform a step of deduction is not a (formal) proof.

Comment: @DerekElkins. I apologize for not having told the rules used step by step. Precisely, I wonder whether there is a rule that allows me to write anything I want after " falsum" ( and in case there is such a rule, how it is called). Could you please tell me?

Comment: @DerekElkins. This is not the same thing as "reductio ad absurdum" I think. For here I do not derive the negation of my assumption.

Comment: Sure you can write anything, even scribbles.   Exercise.  Prove A and not-A implies B.  With that falsum becomes a fadish fallacy.  A better proof is to prove two cases, x in C and x not in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: **yes**. In particular, you're over-thinking the syntactic/semantic divide:

> My question deals with the syntactic use of the propositional constant " false" and the official rules governing this use.

Remember that the syntactic side of things is supposed to reflect the semantic side of things *(and vice versa for that matter, depending on which one considers "primitive")*. The semantic observation is paralleled by a syntactic one - which is either an explicit rule, or derivable, in one's proof system - which allows one to syntactically infer any proposition from $\perp$. When included as an explicit rule in the system, this is often called "ex falso quodlibet," although using the same phrase for both the semantic and syntactic sides is a bit of an abuse of language.

---

It's worth making my first sentence below the quote precise - the key is the (strong) **completeness theorem**. Phrased for sequent systems, this says that "$\Gamma\vdash\varphi$" is a derivable sequent whenever every model of $\Gamma$ is also a model of $\varphi$. Since every model of $\perp$ is also a model of $\varphi$ (= semantic ex falso), completeness tells us that "$\perp$ $\vdash\varphi$" is a derivable sequent in our system.

(But the above isn't satisfying until you've seen and understood the completeness theorem so it's a bit putting the cart before the horse in this particular context.)

Answer (score 1):

The proof seems correct.

The steps you want named are:  $\quad\begin{array}{|l} x\notin B\wedge x\in B\\\bot \hspace{15ex}\text{negation elimination}\\x\in\varnothing\hspace{11ex}\text{ex falso quodlibet}\\\end{array}$

Note: some natural deduction proof systems do not have a symbol for falsum, and instead essentially incorporate the two steps into their *negation elimination* rule -- from a contradiction you may derive anything.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what specific formal proof system you are working with and how ity is has defined its syntactic rules.  In the system I use (a Fitch-style system), inferring the falsum from $P%$ and $\neg P$ is called $\bot \ Intro$, and inferring anything from a falsum is called $\bot \ Elim$